# osx 10.9.5 code signing V2 - signing a framework with: bundle format is ambiguous

Tags: macos, frameworks, codesign, osx-gatekeeper

I'am trying to code sign an app bundle on osx mavericks 10.9.5 with format v2. On previous testing the signing on 10.9.5 (13F12) all went well, all frameworks could be signed without error.
Now, on 13F34, the frameworks could not be signed any more. When i try to sign the first framework with:

```
codesign -f -v -s "Developer ID Application: MY AG" "My.app/Contents/Frameworks/4DJavaScript.framework"
```

then the error occurs:

```
My.app/Contents/Frameworks/4DJavaScript.framework: bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework)
```

When I try to code sign the only version (A) of the framework, the signing succeeds, but on signing the main app the error on the framework reappears.
On looking into the info.plist file of the framework there is (in my sense) the correct entry for the type set:

```
Bundle OS Type code FMWK
```

Any suggestions on how to code sign a framework correctly on 10.9.5-13F34?
Thanks, Peter

Comment: Is is necessary that you have to use command line to generate code signing v2?

Answer (score 18):

Your answer didn't work for me so I post mine.

If you previously copied frameworks with `cp -r` command you will have this problem. With `cp -a` this problem doesn't appear. That's happening because of different way of resolving symlinks in these two options.

Comment: This is the correct answer! codesign break, when symlinks get resolved into directories. In a framework, toplevel folders must be symlinks pointing to Versions/Current and Current must be a symlink to the actual version. Usually 'A'.

Signing 'Versions/Current' might be a workaround, if you cannot fix the structure.

Apple, please fix your codesigner, to say something about bad symlink structure, instead of 'bundle format is ambiguous'.

Comment: I owe a big thanks to @JürgenWeigert - I was trying to codesign my app for Catalina and kept getting this error (bundle format). I saw in [codesign docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG313) one reason is a problem with symlinks. I looked inside my app and found the symlink structure wasn't correct, so I manually adjusted it and it worked. Here's [a post that suggests the structure, look for the comments by Dass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871099/creating-symlinks-in-osx-frameworks-inside-app-bundle)

Comment: Thanks bro @JürgenWeigert you saved my day!

Comment: Upvoted this answer. I was running cp -r to copy my app bundle to use in my pkgbuild process. My pkg file ended up failing notarization. Changing to cp -a allows my pkg to be notarized now.

Answer (score 11):

Immediately after posting the bounty on this question, I figured it out. Signing the current version of the framework directly does the trick:

```
codesign -f -v -s "Developer ID Application: My Dev ID" MyFramework.framework/Versions/Current
```

Comment: im facing this issue. I am not getting your solution. please can you tell in detail

Comment: @QadirHussain I'm not sure what more detail there is to add. I simply used the codesign tool to directly sign the current version of the framework's executable very much like the example in my answer.

Comment: Also you have to ensure that your app does not make use of --deep code signing flag

Answer (score 2):

I was using electron-packager and needed to use the --no-deref-symlinks flag and bam working for me

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. In my case the problem was that the .app file I was trying to `codesign` was stroed in a dropbox folder.

Apparently, dropbox resolves symbolic links by default, i.e. symlinks are completely replaced by the data they point to. Read about it [here](http://www.paulingraham.com/dropbox-and-symlinks.html).

The `codesign` command cannot recognize the format of the bundle after dropbox resolves the symlinks.

The solution is to not store the bundle you are trying to `codesign` in a dropbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was inline with @htzfun's answer however it was file zipping that caused the issue.

MacOS Frameworks have a very particular file structure:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html

A File Zip command was resolving symlinks which lead to duplicate files and an ambiguous framework structure. To fix, make sure you're passing an option to preserve symlinks in whichever file zip tool you're using. As of MacOS 13.6, using Finder to compress the Framework works as well (right click -> Compress).

This snippet was helpful in identifying the root cause:

> ## codesign says my bundle format is ambiguous.
>
> codesign thinks your bundle looks a bit like an app and a bit like a framework.
>
> Perhaps you have both Contents and Versions directories, or files in the top directory that match reserved names for directories in a bundle.
> Perhaps there's an Info.plist in an odd place.
> Perhaps a framework was copied incorrectly so the symlinks it contained were converted to normal files.
> In short, put everything in the correct places.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG313